# jquery form field write issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am updating hidden field in form with jquery. it works just fine for first three clicks after that it shows only first element value.

Here is working js fiddle [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/z1sstnud/17/):

when users is clicking on tab the value of fileorurl changes to 1,2 or 3. it works for first 3-5 click but after that the value stocks to only 1. here is html

```
<div class="container" id="upload">
    <div class="row">
        <form id="upload-form2"
              action="http://way2enjoy.com/modules/compress-png/converturl16.php"
              name="arjun"
              method="post"
              enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div id="tab" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                <a href="#fileuu" class="btn btn-default active" data-toggle="tab">
                    <input type="radio" class="changev" value="1">File Upload
                </a>
                <a href="#urluu" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tab">
                    <input type="radio" class="changev" value="2">URL upload
                </a>
                <a href="#linkuu" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tab">
                    <input type="radio" class="changev" value="3">Website Link
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="fileuu">
                    <label for="comment">Click below to choose files:</label>
                    <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple id="input" class="file_input">
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="urluu">
                    <label for="comment">Image Urls to Compress:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" name="urls" id="urls"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="linkuu">
                    <label for="comment">Website URL to Analyze:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" name="file[]" id="urls"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert" id="loading_progress"></div>
            <br>
            <input type="submit"
                   value="Compress »"
                   class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right"
                   id="upload_btn"
                   name="upload_btn">
            <input type="hidden" name="fileorurl" id="myField" value="">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is javascript:

```
<script>
    $('.changev').change(function () {
        var valueuu = $(this).val();
        $("#myField").val(valueuu);
    });
</script>
```

Any help will be useful thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your checkboxes not updating for some strange reason after a few clicks. You can use the `click` event on their parents instead:

```
$('#tab a').on('click', function(){
    var valueuu = $(this).find('input').val(); 
    $("#myField").val(valueuu);
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z1sstnud/18/)

Comment: feeling idiot for self. why i did not think ur solution.

Answer (score 0):

Found it ^^ your radio buttons are getting checked but they aren't getting unchecked so they aren't canceling each other .. because they aren't in the same radio group

You have to put them in a radio group by adding the name attribute with equal value to each

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use a custom attribute for that and listen to Bootstrap events. The default value of the input is 1, because that will be the first active tab.

```js
$(document).on('shown.bs.tab', '#tab > a', function(e) {
  var dataType = $(e.target).attr('data-type');
  $("#myField").val(dataType);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container" id="upload">
  <div class="row">
    <form id="upload-form2" action="http://way2enjoy.com/modules/compress-png/converturl16.php" name="arjun" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div id="tab" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <a href="#fileuu" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tab" data-type="1">File Upload</a>
        <a href="#urluu" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tab" data-type="2">URL upload</a>
        <a href="#linkuu" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tab" data-type="3">Website Link</a>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="fileuu">
          <label for="comment">Click below to choose files:</label>
          <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple id="input" class="file_input">
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="urluu">
          <label for="comment">Image Urls to Compress:</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" name="urls" id="urls"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="linkuu">
          <label for="comment">Website URL to Analyze:</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" name="file[]" id="urls"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert" id="loading_progress"></div>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Compress »" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right" id="upload_btn" name="upload_btn">
      <input type="text" name="fileorurl" id="myField" value="1">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/zyynnzm9/3/

Comment: thanks . your solution is elegant as i am using bootstrap but as i have asked for jquery and i have already accepted that answer cant accept urs , thanks once again